# Deploying an API with Elasticsearch and MongoDB on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, architecture

I am creating an API with Elasticsearch to index and save some data that needs to be retrieved quickly, and saving other data in MongoDB...

I wanted to know what you suggest for me to consider and worry about. Should I create Elasticsearch with multiple nodes, or start with just one? Should I create each component in a separate instance? Should I use Docker-compose and deploy each component on a regular EC2 instance, or use some specific AWS system?
What else should I be concerned about, monitoring logs...?

I wanted something to guide me.